# cpp move some elements before position after this position at std::list

Tags: c++, list, std, splice

I have `std::list` eg. with ints: `9 10 8 25 70 75 30 14 80`

I want to move all elements less than `10` after the `some_position_number` element eg. `= 5`. The initial order of moved objects is important and must be the same as initial after moving.

In other words at the end need to receive `some_position_number` elements that `false` and after them `true`

Like it must be for 1st example: 10 25 70 75 30 **9** **8** 14 80

Second initial: `9 3 8 25 70 75 30 14 80`
Second result: 10 25 70 75 30 **9** **3** **8** 14 80

Third initial: `25 70 75 30 14 9 3 8 80`
Third result: `25 70 75 30 14 9 3 8 80` (the same already 5 at the beginning)

4 initial: `3 4 1 2 3 9 3 8 80`
4 result: `9 3 8 80 3 4 1 2 3` (something like this) seems here `some_position_number` must be used as threshold or `80 3 4 1 2 3 9 3 8` also accepted, but seems need to check for end() and for infinity loop?

How to do this most effective way, maybe without additional `list` to avoid unnecessary objects creation and erasing? because at the real app there is no ints at the `std::list`, but objects. Maybe std::splice? Somehow select objects that need to move, than find new position and std::splice every element to it.

Comment: `list::splice` can help with moving list nodes without destroying and re-creating.

Comment: thanks, yes, i know, and already add this tag, but my attempts are wrong. I'm confused with iterators when splicing them and when them goes `invalid`. And how to select 9 and 8 to count new position without them... Already post code of my attemts at the previous question, but it adds confusion and I delete it and create new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's ugly, but it works](http://www.greatvwads.com/pix/ad24.htm) and I believe it properly handles all iterator invalidation situation correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

list<int> l;

// prototypes for various helpers of no consequence to the question
void  init();
bool my_pred( list<int>::value_type val);
void dump_list( list<int> const& l);


typedef list<int>::iterator iter_t;

int main() 
{
    init();
    dump_list(l);

    // we want to remove elements that meet the predicate until
    // there are `some_position_number` elements that didn't meet 
    // the predicate

    int some_position_number = 5;
    list<int> tmp_list;

    iter_t i = l.begin();
    for (int count = 0; count < some_position_number && i != l.end(); ) {
        iter_t tmp(i);
        ++i;
        if (my_pred(*tmp)) {
            tmp_list.splice( tmp_list.end(), l, tmp); // remove an element
        }
        else {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    // now i points at the position we want to insert the elements we removed:

    l.splice( i, tmp_list);

    dump_list(l);
}




bool my_pred( list<int>::value_type val)
{
    return val < 10;
}

void  init()
{
    l.push_back(9);
    l.push_back(10);
    l.push_back(8);
    l.push_back(25);
    l.push_back(70);
    l.push_back(75);
    l.push_back(30);
    l.push_back(14);
    l.push_back(80);
}

void dump_list( list<int> const& l)
{
    for (list<int>::const_iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i) {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

The keys are:

- the iterator `i` that's used to walk the range of elements that might be moved has to be copied then incremented before calling `splice()`. When `splice()` is called, the original `i` (now `tmp`) is invalidated.
- we splice the elements that we want to move on to a temporary list.  While this requires a second list, it still doesn't involve a copy of the elements - we're just moving them somewhere else to keep bookkeeping easy.
- keep a count of the elements that didn't meet the predicate - this lets use figure out the insertion point as we move along checking for elements to move.

Comment: thanks, yes, its almost exactly what i need, but seems its my mistake with description. (its my english skills, sorry :( ) but new_position is not fixed, and its `5` not `7` eg. get `my_pred(*tmp)`= 5 ints that false, then move true elements. if initial: `9 **3** 8 25 70 75 30 14 80` new list must be `25 70 75 30 14 9 3 8 80` (5 false, then new). Seems your example can be modification, but somehow need to avoid situation when the range is to low to get requested range. (eg. if from start all emements = true go not before `insert_point` )

Comment: i am sitting, thinking and trying. In other words the question seems can be described how: 'substitute true ints with the closest false while they will not be at the `position`', but also ugly :(

Comment: @abrahab It's not very clear what you want. Does `some_position_number` depend on *how many* elements need to be moved? (you should edit your question, too)

Comment: @jrok `some_position_number` at the end of sorting show how many `false` elements must be before moved true-elements (and maybe threshold of iterations?). but there is also problem with range check and infinite loop if all elements at list is true all there is not enough false elements. Does not know right now how to describe when stop push them back.

Comment: @abrahab: I've modified the example to follow what I think is your clarified intention.  It does use a second list, but since all the move operations are still splices, there's no copying of the elements, just updating of the list pointers.

Comment: @MichaelBurr yes, thanks, its the best logic, but not for all cases. I updated the question with some additional examples and already trying to use your code and make what I need from it exactly.

Comment: @abrahab: I think the updated answer meets those additional tests (it produces the 'alternate' acceptable output for test #4). For test #4 I think it would  add a lot of complexity to come up with a solution that produces the `9 3 8 80 3 4 1 2 3` output, but I haven't thought about it much.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Will try updated version, give me few minutes. Now, i am thinking at this logic: go from the beginning and count steps with true. when first false, move it up for `counted_steps`, then start from the beginner. do that while counted_steps != `some_position_number` or list.end(?)

Comment: @MichaelBurr Amazing, its works like its need! I am about your updated version! :) Many, many thanks! Will try some additional tests, but seems that its do whats I need!